# getting specific groups of patterns inside a block text

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get this values - `10.547.889/0001-85`, `00.219.460/0001-05` separated by groups, but the condition is that the pattern need start with `executada(s):`, can't be something like: `r' - CNPJ:? (?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/\d+-\d+)'`. So, the idea is start in `executada(s)` and get this groups.

Currently, my pattern just get the first group, I don't know how to get all them.

I'm using Python 3.8.5 and regex lib(doesn't re).

```
text = """
Solicite-se ao BANCO CENTRAL, via protocolo digital - SISBACEN ,
o BLOQUEIO de créditos existentes até o limite de R$ 30.257,45 (trinta mil, duzentos e
cinquenta e sete reais e quarenta e cinco centavos) da(s) executada(s): J.HENRIQUE
GALVANI COMERCIO DE ROUPAS - ME - CNPJ 10.547.889/0001-85, Riane Confecções de
Roupas Ltda - ME - CNPJ: 00.219.460/0001-05, Jose Henrique Galvani - CPF: 234.846.406-34
e Heliane Leonel Raymundo Galvani - CPF: 813.460.347-53, porventura
existentes junto a instituições financeiras, incluindo cartões de crédito, agenciadores
de pagamento, administradores de consórcio."""

pattern = r'executad\w(?:\(s\))?\W+(?:[\p{L}\s\-\.]+CNPJ\W+(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/\d+-\d+),)+'

for item in regex.finditer(pattern, text, flags=regex.I|regex.S):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

> {'cnpj': '00.219.460/0001-05'}

I was waiting for:

> {'cnpj': '00.219.460/0001-05'}

> {'cnpj': '10.547.889/0001-85'}

So, can someone help me with this trouble?

Comment: Note that `flags=regex.S|regex.S` = `flags=regex.S` and it is redundant in your regex.

Comment: oopss, I was supposed to put `flags=regex.I|regex.S`. Thanks for warn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex module, you could make use of the `\G` anchor:

```
(?:executad\w(?:\(s\))?\W+|\G(?!^)),?[\p{L}\s.-]+CNPJ\W+\K(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+-\d+)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `executad\w` Match `executad`, a word char (which could also be an `a` char if that is the only possibility)
  - `(?:\(s\))?\W+` Optionally match `(s)` and 1+ non word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current postion at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string
- `)` Close non capture group
- `,?[\p{L}\s.-]+` Match an optional `,` and 1+ times any letter, whitespace char, `.` or `-`
- `CNPJ\W+` Match `CNPJ` and 1+ times non word chars
- `\K` Clear the match buffer to forget what is matched so far
- `(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+-\d+)` Named group **cnpj**, capture the desired format

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jnuHQd/1) |  [Python demo](https://tio.run/##XVPdbtMwFL4mT3GouEi0JEuXdOsqoOpK2Tq6tqQMLghIluMVT4md2U7p@HketGvEE/TByvHSASKSLZ2c833f@XN1az5JEW@3vKykMqDYkq0dpyLGMCXgGaiW2@@xNaO1IXn2GY3M1Znn9bN3e9@yU7f/@KPn@f33WfV18j3TYfBhbzidn6M3e@X250@pqK6fZ/leFj5c@3gCPF7LcQxbGxRxWwtZcMoNCzQDIuFkMB3OYDiavkkHEx9WnEClpJFUFhJyvuSGFBDAYrw4GWAU@JloOY9aCJzMXl@OxjPIGVC1ucu5kRrYmmvDhGEaiNncgYSCl6hmo9InEEfhQefITzrgGsWFIVDywoe8/oIYC2/YKRc3NbNuBpohWjHC0Qs3NVG7/xhDJVBrraT2ICcu3g/9s0YPzsOz0TQdY54N7@lg8nYwHcNwdjFKh5j7ixGks8v5YIElXozwsh2FdhR2kqOw2z3ej6KoHXQ7PqScCAZDKa4Y3fzY/MIC8122qawromFicvIvTQ8irLZ9HCaHUcMTIc@5xL6fMaE4VginpFgRwS1i/rIHB3ESdpPDMIkOgzhp2G10cS8@YVKwAlJyW9Yil/@Du@3YSoVxchR0Yh9wy1bYnVqRHdHf0VzX2G0gwIU23NR8V9AVF0RQxhXRPvpoUXOrQ4kyu4L/TNoHsmSCcpJLxXQjgO6KLElpR4n@vOQCFVUTcg@WQm9@Kspl2PIc50oqwNUoUap5DSEmgORMubtX4YNdW6/nAH6VXRjXAsKlwpbnnBrX87bb3w)

For the example data, you can omit the `regex.S` flag as `\W` also matches a newline.

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:executad\w(?:\(s\))?\W+|\G(?!^)),?[\p{L}\s.-]+CNPJ\W+\K(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+-\d+)"

text = ("Solicite-se ao BANCO CENTRAL, via protocolo digital - SISBACEN ,\n"
    "o BLOQUEIO de créditos existentes até o limite de R$ 30.257,45 (trinta mil, duzentos e\n"
    "cinquenta e sete reais e quarenta e cinco centavos) da(s) executada(s): J.HENRIQUE\n"
    "GALVANI COMERCIO DE ROUPAS - ME - CNPJ 10.547.889/0001-85, Riane Confecções de\n"
    "Roupas Ltda - ME - CNPJ: 00.219.460/0001-05, Jose Henrique Galvani - CPF: 234.846.406-34\n"
    "e Heliane Leonel Raymundo Galvani - CPF: 813.460.347-53, porventura\n"
    "existentes junto a instituições financeiras, incluindo cartões de crédito, agenciadores\n"
    "de pagamento, administradores de consórcio.")

for item in regex.finditer(pattern, text):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

Output

```
{'cnpj': '10.547.889/0001-85'}
{'cnpj': '00.219.460/0001-05'}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you:

```
text = """
Solicite-se ao BANCO CENTRAL, via protocolo digital - SISBACEN ,
o BLOQUEIO de créditos existentes até o limite de R$ 30.257,45 (trinta mil, duzentos e
cinquenta e sete reais e quarenta e cinco centavos) da(s) executada(s): J.HENRIQUE
GALVANI COMERCIO DE ROUPAS - ME - CNPJ 10.547.889/0001-85, Riane Confecções de
Roupas Ltda - ME - CNPJ: 00.219.460/0001-05, Jose Henrique Galvani - CPF: 234.846.406-34
e Heliane Leonel Raymundo Galvani - CPF: 813.460.347-53, porventura
existentes junto a instituições financeiras, incluindo cartões de crédito, agenciadores
de pagamento, administradores de consórcio."""

pattern = r'[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2}'

# cut text to start right after executada(s)
text = text.split("executada(s)")[1]

cnpjs = [{"cnpj": cnpj} for cnpj in regex.findall(pattern, text)]

print(cnpjs)
```