# getting same regex groups inside a block of text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I trying to write a pattern to get each CPNJ group inside a this block of text, but the condition is that, is needed starts with `executados:` and ends with a CNPJ group. But, my pattern always get the last group, I don't know what I should do for it's works.

The answer [getting specific groups of patterns inside a block text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69636185/getting-specific-groups-of-patterns-inside-a-block-text) does not works!

[image: regex101]

pattern: `(?:executados\:)[\p{L}\s\D\d]+CNPJ\W+(?P<cnpj>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/\d+-\d+)`

string to test:

```
Dados dos executados:
1. FOO TEST STRING LTDA., CNPJ: 88.888.888/8888-88,
2. ANOTHER TEST STRING LTDA LTDA LTDA - ME, CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99,
3. FOO TEST STRING LTDA., CPF: 999.999.999-99,
4. FOO TEST STRING LTDA., CPF: 999.999.999-99.
Como medida de economia e celeridade processuais, atribuo a
```

I would to get the values `{'cnpj': ['88.888.888/8888-88', '99.999.999/9999-99']}`, this way is getting just the last.

Comment: Use a regular approach like https://ideone.com/tVQC61

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw it, but I need that condition be respected, in this case, not get simple the CNPJ group, but, get all CNPJ group after `executados:`

Comment: Yes, and you get only those! Did you notice `text[text.index("executados:"):])`?

Comment: hmm, sry, I saw it now! But, it's possible specift it in the pattern instead of code?

Comment: Only as TheFourthBird showed, with PyPi regex module. See [this demo](https://tio.run/##lZFNa8MwDIbv@RUil8Zr4rJ1F5eVUNp0H6xJaQ275OLF2mZI4uA4kP36zFnZKIwNdngEEnol9Kp5t2@6ng@DqhptLBh8xd6z2FtYgu/7GyF1CyPYY9HZMV14lxS2WQY8OXI48sN9eguPfLOiIazT/cMCGKPsxMzBIsZC74rCKs34XXL4oTsLEeySv6bMf9@8346Sb81n@/V/2qm31pWGCqWSAiQCFrrWlRKAUGCJxpVdtTG6wLbthGpDENao506DcF55jVG1DU4e0hdVS1GWgZkEcUuC@GZ55iC9iMl4ZP40DXI5zelXmDkiB5mEMH6BABmGDw).

Comment: nice, have an website to test this regex? I tryied in the regex101 and `(?s)` does not works

Comment: Yes, [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%28%3f%3c%3dexecutados%3a.*%3f%29CNPJ%5cW%2b%28%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%2f%5cd%2b-%5cd%2b%29&i=Dados+dos+executados%3a%0d%0a1.+FOO+TEST+STRING+LTDA.%2c+CNPJ%3a+99.999.999%2f9999-99%2c%0d%0a2.+ANOTHER+TEST+STRING+LTDA+LTDA+LTDA+-+ME%2c+CNPJ%3a+99.999.999%2f9999-99%2c%0d%0a3.+FOO+TEST+STRING+LTDA.%2c+CPF%3a+999.999.999-99%2c%0d%0a4.+FOO+TEST+STRING+LTDA.%2c+CPF%3a+999.999.999-99.%0d%0aComo+medida+de+economia+e+celeridade+processuais%2c+atribuo+a).

Comment: nice, thanks a lot bro!

Comment: When using a regex engine that does not support variable-length lookbehinds, but does support variable-length lookaheads, there are many problems, such as this one, that can be solved by matching the string reversed and then reversing the matches. Here one could match the reversed string with the regex `(?s)\d{2}\-\d{4}\/\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}(?= +:JPNC\b.*:sodatucexe\b)`. This produces two idential matches of `99-9999/999.999.99`...

Comment: ...Upon reversing this match we obtain `"99.999.999/9999-99"`. (Had the matches differed the latter would precede the former in the original string.) [Python re demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1QTeA/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PyPi regex module with the regex like

```cs
(?s)(?<=executados:.*?)CNPJ\W+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+-\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3Dexecutados%3A.%2A%3F%29CNPJ%5CW%2B%28%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%2F%5Cd%2B-%5Cd%2B%29&i=Dados%20dos%20executados%3A%0D%0A1.%20FOO%20TEST%20STRING%20LTDA.%2C%20CNPJ%3A%2099.999.999%2F9999-99%2C%0D%0A2.%20ANOTHER%20TEST%20STRING%20LTDA%20LTDA%20LTDA%20-%20ME%2C%20CNPJ%3A%2099.999.999%2F9999-99%2C%0D%0A3.%20FOO%20TEST%20STRING%20LTDA.%2C%20CPF%3A%20999.999.999-99%2C%0D%0A4.%20FOO%20TEST%20STRING%20LTDA.%2C%20CPF%3A%20999.999.999-99.%0D%0AComo%20medida%20de%20economia%20e%20celeridade%20processuais%2C%20atribuo%20a).

Here is the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##lZFNa8MwDIbv@RUil8Zr4rJ1F5eVUNp0H6xJaQ275OLF2mZI4uA4kP36zFnZKIwNdngEEnol9Kp5t2@6ng@DqhptLBh8xd6z2FtYgu/7GyF1CyPYY9HZMV14lxS2WQY8OXI48sN9eguPfLOiIazT/cMCGKPsxMzBIsZC74rCKs34XXL4oTsLEeySv6bMf9@8346Sb81n@/V/2qm31pWGCqWSAiQCFrrWlRKAUGCJxpVdtTG6wLbthGpDENao506DcF55jVG1DU4e0hdVS1GWgZkEcUuC@GZ55iC9iMl4ZP40DXI5zelXmDkiB5mEMH6BABmGDw):

```py
import regex
text = """Dados dos executados:
1. FOO TEST STRING LTDA., CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99,
2. ANOTHER TEST STRING LTDA LTDA LTDA - ME, CNPJ: 99.999.999/9999-99,
3. FOO TEST STRING LTDA., CPF: 999.999.999-99,
4. FOO TEST STRING LTDA., CPF: 999.999.999-99.
Como medida de economia e celeridade processuais, atribuo a"""
print( regex.findall(r'(?s)(?<=executados:.*?)CNPJ\W+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+-\d+)', text) )
```

yielding

```
['99.999.999/9999-99', '99.999.999/9999-99']
```

The regex matches

- `(?s)` - `regex.DOTALL`, enables `.` to match line break chars
- `(?<=executados:.*?)` - right before the current location, there must be `executados:` and then any zero or more chars
- `CNPJ` -  a fixed string
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+/\d+-\d+)` - the return value of `regex.findall`, Group 1: one or more digits and a `.` twice, then one or more digits, `/`, `one or more digits,` -` and one or more digits.

Comment: Module `regex` is great and definitely works in some situations. But, Python official module`re` for RE handling has warned about the [non-support](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/re.py#L55) for fixed-width _lookbehind_.  It might be better to use fix-width _lookbehind_ (i.e., `((?<=executados).)*`), which is based on the official module `re`. It's a fact that`re` has much more likely stable performance than any other counterparts, since [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) had 40k+ stars, while [regex](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex) got merely dozens.